# Weird characters at the end of openssl dhparam output file

Tags: openssl

When I generated a diffie-hellman prime number using openssl, the output file had some weird characters at the end and I wanted to understand what it means.

**Background info:**

My goal was to generate a safe prime number for use with Diffie-Hellman which is at least 500 bits long, and compatible with generator 5.

**These are the terminal commands I used:**

```
mymacbookname myname$ openssl dhparam -out dh512.der 512 -5 -outform DER -text
Generating DH parameters, 512 bit long safe prime, generator 5
This is going to take a long time
.......................+.+..+..........+............+........+................+....................+................................+.+...............................................................+......+.......+.............................+........+............................+............+..................+................+..........+..............+........................................+.....+............................................+.............+......+...........+....+..........................................+.........................................................+..........................+.................................+................+...+............+...+....................+................+....+...+.+.....................+......................+..............+..................++*++*++*++*++*++*
mymacbookname myname$
```

**I renamed the file "dh512.der" to "dh512.der.txt" and this is what was in the text file:** (This is for a class project and will not be used in any important key-exchange.)

```
Diffie-Hellman-Parameters: (512 bit)
    prime:
        00:9f:71:b9:ea:51:1e:95:d2:9a:66:65:bd:d2:a1:
        31:bd:6d:58:0d:59:06:c4:43:e2:53:34:03:f9:5b:
        c7:4e:48:1e:b0:1f:2c:7f:16:ff:1d:47:26:7d:4d:
        14:63:42:cf:ba:42:ee:06:83:6d:e6:f9:f0:6a:5a:
        fb:ca:66:da:87
    generator: 5 (0x5)
0FAüqπÍQï“öfeΩ“°1ΩmX YƒC‚S4˘[«NH∞,ˇG&}McBœ∫BÓÉmÊ˘jZ˚ f⁄á
```

I'm pretty sure that

```
            00:9f:71:b9:ea:51:1e:95:d2:9a:66:65:bd:d2:a1:
            31:bd:6d:58:0d:59:06:c4:43:e2:53:34:03:f9:5b:
            c7:4e:48:1e:b0:1f:2c:7f:16:ff:1d:47:26:7d:4d:
            14:63:42:cf:ba:42:ee:06:83:6d:e6:f9:f0:6a:5a:
            fb:ca:66:da:87
```

is the prime number I am seeking in hex format separated by `:`'s. **But I am just curious about this part:**

```
0FAüqπÍQï“öfeΩ“°1ΩmX YƒC‚S4˘[«NH∞,ˇG&}McBœ∫BÓÉmÊ˘jZ˚ f⁄á
```

**What is that there for? What does it mean?** I looked at the manual page https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/dhparam.html and it has no description of what the output files will contain.

Thanks!

---

**Update:**

I tried viewing the PEM file as text, so I changed the option from DER to PEM.

**Terminal command:**

```
openssl dhparam -out dh512pem.txt 512 -5 -outform PEM -text
```

**Terminal output:**

```
Generating DH parameters, 512 bit long safe prime, generator 5
This is going to take a long time
......................................+...............................+........................................+...................+.........................+....+..........................................................................................................+.......................+............+........+...+..+................+.........................+......+.....................+........................+.........................................+..............................................+..........+..............................................+.........................+......+..............+...........+..+...............................................+....................................+..........+....................+.........+...................+........+.....................+..............................................+..+............+................+...............................+.+.............+.....................................+.............+............................+.......+.......................................................+...................+.........+.........+.................+..............+..........+.+..+.................................+.......+........+...............+....................+..................+.............+............+.........+...............++*++*++*++*++*++*
```

**Contents of dh512pem.txt:**

```
Diffie-Hellman-Parameters: (512 bit)
    prime:
        00:d6:23:97:87:75:2d:88:73:24:26:dc:be:c9:70:
        21:81:02:7d:ca:be:10:89:ba:57:f0:e1:2f:ca:b0:
        da:fd:5d:67:c9:51:f9:8c:e8:f2:20:dd:23:72:e5:
        a0:79:1c:ad:98:93:3e:c2:14:18:f9:02:5a:1a:0e:
        5a:d8:de:68:27
    generator: 5 (0x5)
-----BEGIN DH PARAMETERS-----
MEYCQQDWI5eHdS2IcyQm3L7JcCGBAn3KvhCJulfw4S/KsNr9XWfJUfmM6PIg3SNy
5aB5HK2Ykz7CFBj5AloaDlrY3mgnAgEF
-----END DH PARAMETERS-----
```

I am thinking that it output the DER format after printing the text (hex) version. Because when I switched to PEM format, it output base64 after printing the text version.

**Source backing up this idea: Man page** https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/dhparam.html

> -inform DER|PEM This specifies the input format. The DER option uses an ASN1 DER encoded form compatible with the PKCS#3 DHparameter
>   structure. The PEM form is the default format: it consists of the DER
>   format base64 encoded with additional header and footer lines.
>
> -outform DER|PEM This specifies the output format, the options have the same meaning as the -inform option.

Comment: You are right the first output you saw is the DER output, except that is should be on the line *after* "generator: 5 (0x5)" DER is at least partly binary (in this case entirely so) which looks like gibberish when written to a terminal or printer. AIUI when you find the answer yourself the best procedure is to enter it so the question doesn't continue to show as open http://security.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer .

Comment: Ok. I was just waiting for someone to confirm that my idea was right. You're right, there was a newline in there but somehow it didn't show up, so I put it back.

Answer (score 0):

My idea when I updated my question was correct. Thanks to dave_thompson_085 for confirming that it was the DER output. That DER output is the same output that would have been there if I hadn't put the "-text" option. The text option made it print "human-readable" format in *addition* to the DER output.